# NSOutlineView and several models

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface, nsoutlineview

can somebody point me to sample open source application or tutorial or brief description, how create table view where items grouped by(I think its `NSOutlineView`, right?). For example, I have products grouped by categories and looking for table which look like this:

```
| Product name | Product cost |

- Category1

| product1 name | $100 |

| product2 name | $200 |

- Category2

| product3 name | $100 |

| product4 name | $200 |
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use an `NSOutlineView`. Apple has [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SourceView/index.html) that shows exactly how to do this.

Comment: Yes, I know about this sample but what i mean exactly is example outlineview when several models use as category->>products